# Fortran77 parameter when executing program

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am currently doing a Fortran77 assignment, so please don't tell me the exact coding, but please give me a hint of what I want to do:

Using UNIX terminal, I would like to get the parameter passed on by executing

```
./program.exe parameter
```

Comment: Please don't use the tag homework it is **obsolete**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In standard Fortran77 you can't.  End of story.  Accessing command line arguments with fortran programs wasn't standardized until Fortran 2003.

If you're using the GNU fortran compiler, you can use the [`iargc()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IARGC.html) and [`getarg(i, arg)`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETARG.html) functions, which return the number of arguments and the value of a specific argument, resepectively.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to access command line arguments in FORTRAN77.

Given below is the code fragment I use :

```
  CHARACTER ARGV*10
  N=IARGC()
  CALL GETARG(1,ARGV)
```

Just do ./a.out 1 2 3

ARGV will store the value of the first argument, i.e, 1

To convert this argument to float, use

```
  READ (ARGV,*) RARG
```

RARG will convert ARGV into a floating-point integer.