# How to send command line input to a Fortran subroutine?

Tags: fortran

**Update**: *`get_command_argument` sounds really helpful, however, I believe am using an older version of Fortran. (I think 90?)*

I am new to Fortran and need to use a Fortran code to calculate something. I need to call this Fortran code repeatedly from a Matlab program that would be impractical to rewrite in Fortran, so I am using the "system" command in matlab to call the program, which is basically like calling from the command line. Currently, the the fortran code contains a main function and several subroutines (the main one, FUNFIT, is dependent on the others and takes X, Y as inputs), and currently looks something like this:

```
  implicit double precision (A-H), double precision (O-Z)
  X = 5;
  Y = 7;
  call FUNFIT(X,Y,Pn,FN,UN,CV,CH,CHI,PM,US)
  end

  subroutine FUNFIT(X, Y, Pn,FN,UN,CV,CH,CHI,PM,US)
  *I don't think details are needed here*
  end
  
  subroutine SOME_OTHER_SUBROUTINE( . . .)
```

I want to be able to call FUNFIT from the command line (allowing it to have access to the other subroutines) and input X, Y. So basically, I want to directly call FUNFIT from a shell, with inputs given.

However, I am having trouble with calling the code and defining the inputs. I have not been able to find an example of a Fortran "main" function with an input. If I just compile it with the "main" function commented out, I don't know how to call FUNFIT. How can I call FUNFIT (either directly, or through the use of a main function) from the command line and directly input values of X, Y each time? I am at a loss. I know it is ridiculous, but my first attempt has been to re-write and re-compile the program with new values of X, Y each time I call it, which has been prohibitively slow. Thanks for helping out this novice Fortran programmer.

Comment: The linked question leads to one example of using `get_command_argument`, and you can find other examples using that subroutine's name for search.  If this isn't exactly what you are after with your question, please update it to provide more detail.

Comment: The Matlabby way of doing this is to encapsulate the Fortran routine(s) you want to use in a *MEX* file.  For which activity there is a ton of informative resources available at your favourite search engine.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support the Fortran 2003 features required, then you have to rely on a non-standard alternative (such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14652225/3157076) ).  Or indeed the MEX interfacing mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: Or get a newer compiler; F2003 is 15(-ish) years old at this point.

Comment: We have other duplicates about the other older options, there is no need to reopen.  However, you *really* have to say which exact compiler you have because those older ways are compiler-specific.

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652225/fortran77-parameter-when-executing-program and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932163/how-to-get-command-line-arguments-in-openvms-fortran and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369096/implementing-getarg-subroutine-call